# How to make the following JavaScript code work and result in a list of names and ages inside the element with ID "myDivId" :

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

> How to make the following JavaScript code work and result in a list
>   of names and ages inside the element with ID "myDivId" :

```
<div id="myDivId">No results yet</div>
<script>
new PersonPrinter("myDivId",[{"name":"Joe","age":"23"}      
{"name":"Sam","age":"31"}]).render();
</script>`
```

Comment: Sorry to be so unclear, I basically do not understand the question myself as I was asked to complete this as a task, this was the exact question. Any suggestions? I'm so confused :/

Answer (score 1):

```
In the PersonPrinter render function you need to update the div

PersonPrinter.prototype.render = function(id,data) {
var elem = document.elementById(id);
for (var i =0;i <data.length;i++) {

var d = dcoument.createElement('div');
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'+data.name +'  Age:'+data.age');
elem.appendChild(d);`enter code here`
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access div id using innerHTML

```
var a = Document.getElementById('myDinId');
```

And for changing value use simply = operator

```
a.innerHTML = 'Something';
```